# On a step of a proof of the Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, products, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

This is an excerpt taken from *Probability with Martingales* by Williams.

The framework is probability theory.

---

[image]

---

Why is the equation being discussed true if condition $\{ n \ge m \}$ is replaced by condition $\{ r \ge n \ge m \}$?

And what is meant then saying that the limit as $r \uparrow \infty$ is justified by the monotonicity of the two sides? Is he taking the limit?

In general I do not understand what is happening in that part of the proof :)

Comment: Independence only deals with finite products. The author says that independence gives the equation for finite products/intersections and that monotonicity allows to extend it to products/intersections over every $n\geqslant m$ (with $m$ fixed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a notation issue:
$$\Pi_{n \geq m} (1-p_n) = \lim_{r \to \infty}  \Pi_{r \geq n \geq m} (1-p_n). $$ This is the analog of $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n = \lim_{r \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^r a_n$. The infinite product is the limit (when it exists) of the partial products

You might see this as a consequence of the limit in the sets under consideration:
$$\cap_{n \geq m} A_n^c = \lim_{r \to \infty} \cap_{r \geq n \geq m} A_n^c $$ 
and

$$P(\cap_{n \geq m} A_n^c) = P(\lim_{r \to \infty} \cap_{r \geq n \geq m} A_n^c) = \lim_r P(\cap_{r \geq n \geq m} A_n^c) \overset{\text{ind.}}{=} \lim_r \Pi_{r \geq n \geq m} P(A_n^c) = \lim_r \Pi_{r \geq n \geq m}(1-p_n)   $$

Comment: Thus, this is a *definitional* issue, not a notational one.